# AddRowTable in jQuery selectively write in input box

Tags: jquery, html-table, autofill

How do I get the value clicked in each row (generated using AddRowTable plugin), i.e.,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
$(".addRow-Max4").btnAddRow({maxRow:4, inputBoxAutoNumber:true});
$(".delRow").btnDelRow();
});
</script>
```

generates maximal 4 rows in a table and numbers each input box, so I get textfield1, textfield2 and so onin my table.

```
<table border="0" >
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Input your data</th>
    <th><input type="button" value="Add Row" class="addRow-Max4"/></th>
</tr>
<tr><td>
    <a href="#" class="autofill">Apple</a> 
    <a href="#" class="autofill">Banana</a> 
    <a href="#" class="autofill">Mango</a>
    </td><td><input type="text" name="textfield" class="autofill" size="25"/></td>
    <td><img src="./images/cross.gif" class="delRow" border="0"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I might decide for Apple in row1, Mango in row2 and so on and would like that the according textfield for this row is filled.

I tried something like:

```
$("a[class=autofill]").click(function()
{
$("input[name=textfield]").val($(this).text());
return false;
});
```

but do not get it to work for the different textfields.

Any ideas?

Ok now I have

```
$("a[class=autofill]").live("click", function(){
$("input[name=textfield1]").val($(this).text());
return false;
});
```

but how do I have to adjust it to make it dynamic for each row. Let's say textfield1, textfield2, textfield3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I just took a quick look, but I think maybe `click()` is not taking effect on elements used after the click event is defined.  Try `live()` instead:  `$("a[class=autofill]").live("click", function(){ ... });`

Comment: If these rows are added after the page has loaded, you cannot bind events to them as you have done. Zach L is correct that you have to use "live" to bind events to elements added to the DOM after the page is loaded. You can also use .delegate()

Comment: ok using "live" now. One more question: how to call each different row here: $("input[name=textfield]").val($(this).text()); Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  I am kindof confused as to what exactly you want.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I edited my post, hopefully it is more clear what I want to do now...